# How to change order of factor levels in ggplot facet wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a factor with levels Xa, aXa and aX. Since R treats the factors in alphabetical order, the default facet wraps are coming as aX, aXa and Xa. I want the Xa to be the first graph in the wrap. I tried the following code:

```
data_small<- read.csv("agg_cond_subj_123.csv")
data_small<-fct_relevel(data_small$pos, "Xa", "aXa", "aX")
```

And then fed it to ggplot:

```
data_small %>%
  ggplot(aes(lg, prop))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~pos)+
  labs(x="Language group",
   y="Accuracy (%)")
```

Xa was still treated in the last order. I tried piping it directly through fct_reorder()

```
data_small %>%
  fct_reorder(pos, "Xa", "aXa", "aX")
  ggplot(aes(lg, prop))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~pos)+
  labs(x="Language group",
   y="Accuracy`enter code here` (%)")
```

but it gave an error: Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector).

I looked at some related solutions on the platform already but they were not fulfilling my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use functions that relevel the factor variable inside `mutate`:

```
data_small %>%
  mutate(pos = factor(pos, levels = c("Xa", "aXa", "aX"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(lg, prop))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~pos)+
  labs(x="Language group",
   y="Accuracy`enter code here` (%)")
```