# calculating distibution based on different columns and then plotting several histogram in R

Tags: r

I would like calculate the distribution (and plot histograms) of the column `gap` based on groups of (columns) `user_id` & `As` with respect to changes in the column `type`. Then, plot these distributions.

lest say sample data is

```
userID   As   type   gap
1        a1    D     3.45
1        a1    P     4.44
1        a1    P     5.12
```

So the histogram should be based on groupby(userId, As) and show the distribution of the column `gap` from the perspective in changes in the column `type` such as of D-P (means row with D to the next row with P) and P-P as example above.

my desire output is having a set of histograms for gaps. That means that the distribtuion based on the column `type` when you have, for example, `D` then `P`
I can imagine a table of histograms like this: (NA if there is no distribution)

```
     D          P         E       A

D  HistDD      HistDP   HistDE   HistDA

P   NA         HistPP     etc.

E    

A
```

Update: to make the solution easier, I created a new column `transition` which contains all `gap` based on `type` changes.

```
df<- df%>% 
group_by(userID,As)%>% 
mutate(transition=paste0(type,"-",lead(type)))
```

So now it looks like:

```
userID   As   type   gap    transition
1        a1    D     3.45    D-P
1        a1    P     4.44    P-P
1        a1    P     5.12    P-NA
```

Therefore, new need to plot the histogram of `gap` with the label of the column `transition`. (not sure how this helpful ¯\*(ツ)*/¯ )

This is dput() of my data

```
structure(list(userID = c(67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 
67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 
67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 
67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 
115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 
115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 
115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 
115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 
115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 
115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 
115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 
115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 
115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 
115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 
115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 
115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 
123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 
123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 
123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 
123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 
123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 
123952L, 123952L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 
125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 
125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 
125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 
125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 
125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 
125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 
125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 
136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 
136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 
136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 
136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 
136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 
136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 139301L, 139301L, 
139301L, 139301L, 139301L, 139301L), As = c("a1", "a1", "a1", 
"a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", 
"a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", 
"a5", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", 
"a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", 
"a1", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", 
"a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", 
"a3", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", 
"a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", 
"a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", 
"a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a1", "a1", "a1", 
"a1", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", 
"a3", "a3", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a5", "a5", "a5", 
"a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", 
"a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", 
"a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", 
"a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", 
"a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", 
"a3", "a3", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", 
"a5", "a5", "a5", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", 
"a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", 
"a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", 
"a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a5", "a1", 
"a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1"), type = c("D", "D", "P", "P", "E", 
"E", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", 
"A", "A", "D", "D", "E", "E", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "P", 
"P", "E", "E", "E", "E", "A", "A", "E", "E", "P", "P", "E", "E", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "D", "P", "P", "E", "E", "A", "A", "E", 
"E", "A", "A", "A", "A", "E", "E", "D", "D", "E", "E", "A", "A", 
"D", "D", "P", "P", "E", "E", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", 
"E", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "P", "P", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"A", "A", "E", "E", "P", "P", "E", "E", "A", "A", "E", "E", "A", 
"A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "A", "A", "D", "D", 
"E", "E", "A", "A", "D", "D", "E", "E", "A", "A", "D", "D", "P", 
"P", "P", "P", "E", "E", "E", "E", "A", "A", "E", "E", "A", "A", 
"E", "E", "D", "D", "P", "P", "E", "E", "A", "A", "P", "P", "E", 
"E", "A", "A", "A", "A", "E", "E", "A", "A", "D", "D", "P", "P", 
"E", "E", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "A", "A", "D", 
"D", "E", "E", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "P", "P", 
"E", "E", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "P", "P", "E", "E", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "D", "D", "P", "P", "E", "E", "A", "A", "E", "E", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "D", "E", "E", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "P", "P", "E", "E"), gap = c(13.3166666666667, 
467.133333333333, 0.483333333333333, 850.116666666667, 1.83333333333333, 
1652.38333333333, 0.416666666666667, NA, 3.16666666666667, NA, 
3.18333333333333, 10700.9166666667, 0.45, NA, 19.6333333333333, 
2294.61666666667, 0.0833333333333333, 4852.63333333333, 1.46666666666667, 
NA, 4.15, 11090.5333333333, 1.83333333333333, 23652.4833333333, 
9.9, NA, 0.55, 1352, 1.15, 71.1, 1.58333333333333, 1370.65, 0.233333333333333, 
10256.2333333333, 1.56666666666667, 1036.75, 0.95, 176.833333333333, 
0.85, 1363.03333333333, 0.15, 1265.98333333333, 0.3, 347.683333333333, 
0.133333333333333, 292.216666666667, 19.55, NA, 8.21666666666667, 
179.316666666667, 0.0166666666666667, 2227.06666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 
9420.28333333333, 0.566666666666667, 1532.7, 0.116666666666667, 
1725.5, 14.1333333333333, 3471.4, 14.2166666666667, NA, 2.15, 
54.65, 0.05, 3100.55, 4.33333333333333, 10759.35, 0.116666666666667, 
NA, 1.3, 3052.8, 0.0833333333333333, 1447.33333333333, 1.1, 333.966666666667, 
0.133333333333333, 1265.2, 2.25, 401.133333333333, 10.75, 218.816666666667, 
8.4, 1304.73333333333, 0.183333333333333, NA, 0.416666666666667, 
11711.65, 3.75, 7640.33333333333, 0.166666666666667, 1283.25, 
0.866666666666667, 1099.65, 6.4, 1944.5, 0.15, 320.316666666667, 
7.98333333333333, 683.7, 11.5, 2393.15, 0.15, 5597.88333333333, 
0.25, 1119.7, 0.683333333333333, 352.533333333333, 6.76666666666667, 
NA, 18.0833333333333, 5664.28333333333, 3.58333333333333, NA, 
6.65, 4337.93333333333, 13.4333333333333, 279.533333333333, 0.5, 
NA, 0.716666666666667, 1700.33333333333, 2.21666666666667, 63.2166666666667, 
3.63333333333333, NA, 7.73333333333333, 5943.25, 2.86666666666667, 
2903.55, 9.55, NA, 1.93333333333333, 27659.9166666667, 19.3333333333333, 
1276.63333333333, 2.83333333333333, 128.65, 0.116666666666667, 
3339.2, 0.433333333333333, 85.8333333333333, 1.18333333333333, 
1691.71666666667, 2.73333333333333, 32.7833333333333, 0.183333333333333, 
146.333333333333, 0.133333333333333, NA, 13.7833333333333, 10144.75, 
0.65, 1550.31666666667, 0.266666666666667, 496.583333333333, 
0.0166666666666667, 862.75, 0.133333333333333, 54.0666666666667, 
0.15, 1453.96666666667, 0.216666666666667, 30.5666666666667, 
0.883333333333333, 445.883333333333, 0.366666666666667, 250.3, 
5.96666666666667, NA, 18.05, 4289.25, 5.73333333333333, 197.35, 
0.133333333333333, 133.816666666667, 0.133333333333333, 6615.91666666667, 
0.0833333333333333, 701.466666666667, 0.85, 12694.65, 5.86666666666667, 
358.766666666667, 0.2, NA, 2.11666666666667, 14430.7666666667, 
0.133333333333333, 230.333333333333, 0.1, NA, 3.93333333333333, 
3233.35, 0.0166666666666667, NA, 0.0833333333333333, 1594.08333333333, 
1.41666666666667, 1361.88333333333, 0.183333333333333, 122.4, 
0.2, NA, 3.86666666666667, NA, 5.01666666666667, 7231.8, 5.6, 
5866.23333333333, 0.55, 1316.96666666667, 0.233333333333333, 
40.8, 0.15, NA, 16.1333333333333, 4183.36666666667, 2.21666666666667, 
1483.13333333333, 0.333333333333333, 82.1166666666667, 0.35, 
1531.9, 0.366666666666667, 124.666666666667, 1.26666666666667, 
107.583333333333, 0.366666666666667, NA, 10.0333333333333, 355.433333333333, 
0.3, 94.6166666666667, 15.5833333333333, 619.85, 0.45, 7923.56666666667, 
3.88333333333333, NA, 2.1, 6907.65, 0.416666666666667, NA, 0.5, 
6427.9, 1.05, 608.616666666667, 0.233333333333333, 1748.33333333333
)), row.names = c(NA, -250L), groups = structure(list(userID = c(67432L, 
67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 67432L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 115883L, 
115883L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 123952L, 125716L, 
125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 125716L, 136983L, 136983L, 136983L, 
136983L, 136983L, 139301L), As = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", 
"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a1", 
"a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a1"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:8, 9:10, 11:14, 15:20, 21:26, 27:48, 
        49:62, 63:70, 71:86, 87:110, 111:114, 115:120, 121:126, 
        127:132, 133:150, 151:170, 171:186, 187:192, 193:196, 
        197:204, 205:206, 207:216, 217:230, 231:240, 241:244, 
        245:250), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `facet_grid` from the `ggplot2` package to arrange the plots in the desired manner.

Setup:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

I'm using your df from above, and instead of defining a transition variable, define current type, next type, and the grouping variable (userID-As):

```
df <- df %>% 
 group_by(userID, As) %>% 
 mutate(curr_type = type, next_type = lead(type)) %>%
 mutate(grp = paste0(userID, "-", As))
```

Given that there are a number of groups, I chose to plot to a PDF

```
pdf("myplots.pdf")
for (i in unique(df$grp)){
  p = ggplot(df %>% filter(grp == i), aes(x = gap)) + geom_histogram() + 
    facet_grid(curr_type ~ next_type) + ggtitle(i)
  print(p)
}
dev.off()
```

- The first line `pdf(...)` creates a PDF titled `myplots.pdf`
- The for loop is over the various groups
- For each group, we filter the df on said group and plot the histogram. So for example, for the first group, you get [image]
- `dev.off()` closes the writing to the PDF (remember to call it; o/w, plots will continue to be routed to the PDF.

If you'd like to see a single plot, set `i = unique(df$grp)[1]` and run the plotting code within the for loop. You can tweak further as desired and once satisfied, re-run the above to write to a PDF.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to change to order of A,D,E,P in the plot?(e.g. making it D, P, E, A)

Comment: @Cina, yes, you can relevel the factors, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70969908/3674399. So you can do `factor(curr_type, levels = c("D", "P", "E", "A", "NA"))` and the same for `next_type`